# An output image file with red contours of all objects

Tags: python, opencv

I have the following code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

image = cv.imread("input1.jpg")
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_denoised =  cv.GaussianBlur(img_gray,(5,5),2)

ret, thresh = cv.threshold(img_denoised, 216, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

kernel = np.ones((1,1),np.uint8)
opening = cv.dilate(thresh, kernel)
opening = cv.erode(opening, kernel)

    # detect the contours on the binary image using cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(image=opening, mode=cv.RETR_TREE, method=cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for i in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv.boundingRect(i)
    cv.drawContours(image, [i], -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    
cv.imshow("A.jpg", image)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNhEq.jpg)
It only shows the stars with a red contours but I want all the text to have a red contours, including the background. Here is the original file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opPkj.jpg)
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why the blurring and morpholical op's ? there's no noise in your image, you're just blurring the edges that you're looking for...

Comment: Why have you removed the images? They are essential to the question. I've rolled back to the previous edit.

Answer (score 1):

I messed with this a bit and the best outcome I could get was the following, I think with some tweaking you could ignore the shading, as I'm converting it to grayscale it seems to be dropping the correct contour on the shapes, but the text is working as expected;

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

src = cv2.imread('c:\\input1.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# blur
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
# canny edge
canny = cv2.Canny(blur, 100, 200)
# dilate
kernel = np.ones((5, 5))
dilate = cv2.dilate(canny, kernel, iterations=1)
# find contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
    dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
# draw contours
cv2.drawContours(src, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

cv2.imshow("a.jpg", src)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image: Output]